# Template edit option not found in back end after apply stencil theme : Bigcommerce Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

I have developed stencil theme and apply on live store.

After apply  stencil theme, Not found template  edit (edit html/css) option in back end like below URL:
https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Accessing-and-Customizing-Template-Files

Can any body help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provided, it denotes that those instructions for edit html/css options are only available in browser for blueprint themes at this time.

Stencil themes are uploaded as archive (.zip) files and do not interact with webdav in any way.

Support is still pending for downloading of themes, which would be required in this case since you are using a theme from the marketplace.

For info and updates, review: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/new-and-pending-features